# Python datetime: format string %-m (%#m) unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime, format

I am trying to format a date in format like '1/1/18' to a datetime object. I think a [proper format string would be '%-m/%-d/%-y'](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime) (or '%#m/%#d/%#y' for Windows), but I couldn't confirm it with the [official Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes). I assume its m/d because of other dates I saw in the spreadsheet (5/28/2018, for example).

I think I have a problem with no-leading-zeros day, month and year. [This site](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime) states that "%-m" (or "%#m" for Windows) would give me the month without a leading zero, so January would return 1 instead of 01. Let's try this:

```
>>> date_obj= datetime(year=2018, month=1, day=1)
>>> date_obj
datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0)
>>> date_obj.strftime("%#m")
'1'
```

Works fine.

Let's run this through a complete date string.

```
>>> format_string = '%#m/%#d/%#y'
```

```
>>> date_obj.strftime(format_string)
'1/1/18'
```

Works fine too.

But when I try to parse this string with `strptime` function:

```
>>> datetime.strptime(format_string, '1/1/18')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '%#m/%#d/%#y' does not match format '1/1/18'
```

So actually a "circular use" of `strptime` and `strftime` results in an exception:

```
>>> datetime.strptime(
        format_string, 
        date_obj.strftime(format_string)
    )

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '%#m/%#d/%#y' does not match format '1/1/18'
```

What is a correct approach to converting a date string '1/1/18' to a datetime object?

I recreated this issue with the IPython console.

```
>>> import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

PS I'm not responsible for this date format, I know there are better ways of presenting dates. I was just asked to work on the data like this and am trying to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attributes are in reverse order.

It sohuld be
`datetime.strptime('1/1/18', format_string)`

Minimal example:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
dt.strptime('1/3/18','%m/%d/%y')
```

help() result on `strptime`:

> Help on built-in function strptime:
>
> strptime(...)
> string, format -> new datetime parsed from a string (like time.strptime()).

Comment: That's true, I don't know how I mistook it for BigQuery notation of FORMAT_DATE. Thank you!

But it unfortunately doesn't resolve my problem.


datetime.strptime(date_obj.strftime(format_string), format_string) raises the ValueError: '#' is a bad directive in format '%#m/%#d/%#y'. And so does "-" when it's in place of "#". Could you help me with that?

Comment: I honestly don't know where you're getting the ```#``` symbol from. Pleasy try the format string from my example.

Comment: I take it from https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime. It worked fine with strftime in the example I provided, so I assumed it's a legit way to transform strings to date as well. Was this ever true? I mean, it's a behaviour that changed across Python versions? EDIT: your solution works fine with all dates I had to work on. Thank you again!

Comment: Is your browser having a display issue? The only hashtags I see on that page are in the [comments in Example 2](https://i.imgur.com/t3poRKa.png).

Comment: @wtarnawski [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) are always a good source

Comment: I mentioned the # in the beginning. Please find that info on https://strftime.org/ under "Platform specific directives". It actually works: when I try these commands: date_obj.strftime("%#m"); date_obj.strftime("%-m"); date_obj.strftime("%m") for first I get 1, for second I get an error and last gives me 01.